It seems the statement "an object in orbit is in a permanent free fall around Earth" is wrong. Is my understanding correct?
Here is an excerpt from an Wikipedia article on low Earth orbit

However, an object in orbit is in a permanent free fall around Earth, because in orbit the gravitational force and the centrifugal force balance each other out....

Another Wikipedia article defines free fall as

[F]ree fall is any motion of a body where gravity is the only force acting upon it....

It seems the two articles conflict with each other. I'm sure the definition of free fall quoted is widely accepted. So, is it necessary to refine the description in the Wikipedia article on LEO?

Welcome to PhysicsSE! Why would you think that the two definitions are conflicting?

Can we assume (from your tag choice) that you only want an answer in terms of Newtonian mechanics, and not General Relativity?

@PM2Ring answers in terms of General Relativity will also be greatly appreciated

Yet another example of why the centrifugal concept has no place in layfolk language. Just confuses people for very little goodness.

even if you see it in an inertial frame, you might say two forces are acting on object, " gravitational and centripetal", but centripetal force is not force in the sense, it is result of gravitational force; gravitational force acts on the object, it must have some acceleration , that acceleration is named as centripetal acceleration and if you multiply it by mass, it's called force.

The centrifugal force is not a "force" in the sense relevant to that definition of freefall.  It is what is known as a "fictitious force," because it derives from the fact that the observer is not in an inertial frame but is constantly being accelerated (by gravity).

Technically, our best current understanding (post Einstein and General Relativity), is that gravity is also a "fictitious" force.  In fact, one characterization of a "fictitious" force is any force that must be added when performing an analysis in a frame of reference to get the forces to balance out when applying Newton's third law - (Force = rate of change of momentum or dP/Dt).

The first sentence in the first article is correct, because there are no real forces acting on an object in orbit. Both Gravity and centrifugal  forces are fictitious.

The statement in the title of your question is correct, an object in orbit [around the earth] is in a permanent freefall.
The first wiki article is incorrect. There is no centrifugal force on the orbiting body. Furthermore, if any force 'balanced' out the gravitational force on the object then the net force on it would be zero and, according to Newton's 1st law, the object would move in a straight line.
The second wiki statement is essentially correct.

Since you said in a comment that an answer based on general relativity would be welcome here is such an answer.
In relativity (both special and general) we can define a property called the proper acceleration. The precise definition of this is a bit involved, but basically the proper acceleration of an observer is the number that an accelerometer held by that observer will show. For example the accelerometer in my phone currently shows 1g, so my proper acceleration is 1g.
The reason we use the proper acceleration is that it is a scalar invariant i.e. it has the same value for all observers. This means it is a quantity that everyone can agree on, and such properties are rare in general relativity.
The statement that an observer is in free fall is simply the statement that their proper acceleration is zero. The Wikipedia article talks about forces acting on the observer, but forces can be complicated things in general relativity so this makes any definition based on forces somewhat involved involved to use. By contrast, the statement that the proper acceleration is zero is straightforward and unambiguous and every observer will agree on it.
The proper acceleration is the magnitude of the four-acceleration vector, and in general relativity this is given by:
$$ A^\alpha = \frac{\mathrm d^2x^\alpha}{\mathrm d\tau^2} + \Gamma^\alpha_{\,\,\mu\nu}U^\mu U^\nu \tag{1} $$
As always with GR explaining exactly what this question means is a little involved, but for our purposes we need only note that if the the proper acceleration is zero then all the component of the four-acceleration, $A^\alpha$, must be zero and we can substitute this in equation (1) to get:
$$ \frac{\mathrm d^2x^\alpha}{\mathrm d\tau^2} = - \Gamma^\alpha_{\,\,\mu\nu}U^\mu U^\nu \tag{2} $$
and this is called the geodesic equation. It is basically the general relativity equivalent of Newton's second law for a freely falling body. The left side describes the coordinate acceleration i.e. how we observe the position of the body to be changing with time, and the right side describes the spacetime curvature i.e. what Newton would have called the gravitational acceleration $g$.
The point of all this is that the statement that an observer is in free fall is equivalent to the statement that their trajectory obeys the geodesic equation, and for an observer orbiting the Earth their trajectory does obey the geodesic equation. Therefore such observers are indeed in free fall, and we can say this without worrying about what (fictitious) forces are acting.

The existence of a centrifugal force, or a Coriolis force, is coordinate dependent.
In ECI (earth centered inertial) coordinates, the satellite needs centripetal force to make it orbit, that force is gravity.
In a frame rotating so that the satellite is stationary, there is a centrifugal force pushing it outward, that is exactly countered by gravity so the satellite remains stationary.
In an earth centered frame with another other angular velocity, there is a centrifugal force that is balanced by the sum of a Coriolis force and gravity that maintains the orbit.
In general relativity, free-fall means "moving on a geodesic" with no fictitious forces. In a reference frame with no fictitious forces ("true zero-g"), that frame is the orbit.
Also: general relativity states that physics is invariant under any coordinate transformation, and what ever that is, "gravitation" restores the normal laws of physics. Gravitation includes:

Newtonian gravity aka "gravity"
The centrifugal force
the Coriolis force

and

any apparent accelerations cause by non-inertial motions associated with the linear motion of the coordinate frame

Frame-dragging if the body being orbited is rotating.

everything else in general relativity, which eventually gets non-linear and is not amenable to nice names like "gravity", "Coriolis", etc...



I would use "frame dependent" instead of "coordinate dependent." A frame of reference is more than a system of coordinates. On the other hand, it is not the difference between cartesian or polar coordinates that introduces apparent forces.

But that's the point: they're not apparent forces, they are gravitation. Theorists tell me GR means "Physics is independent of coordinate diffeomorphisms", and we have coordinates like Kruskal-Szekeres that don't even have $d^2x/dt^2$--but physics still works.

What the Wikipedia statements lack is a clear mention of the frame of reference.
In both examples the system is the body.
However, an object in orbit is in a permanent free fall around Earth, because in orbit the gravitational force and the centrifugal force balance each other out....
In this example the reference frame is the body itself and when observed in this frame the body is not moving.
To be able to use Newton's laws of motion a fictitious force, equal in magnitude and opposite in direction to the gravitational force of attraction of the Earth, is introduced so that the net force on the body is zero.
However, the gravitational attraction of the Earth is the only real force acting on the body which ties in with the other statement, In classical mechanics, free fall is any motion of a body where gravity is the only force acting upon it.
